# My boyfriend wants to come to Canada for 6 months. How much money will he need to be able to come here?

Tags: visas, usa, canada, money

My (American) boyfriend wants to come to Canada for 6 months and we had just found out he needs a specific amount of money to visit here to show he can support himself for the 6 months.

How much money will he need? We need help figuring this out because we aren’t exactly sure. He won’t need to pay for anything though. He will be staying with me and won’t need to pay for living or food or entertainment.

Comment: It should probably be said for future readers: **If anyone is asking you to send them a specific amount of money in order to travel to your country, it is a scam.**  No matter how well you think you know them, how long you have been dating online, etc.

Comment: Where did you find this out from?

Answer (score 4):

## No specific dollar amount is required under the official guidance.

[This Canadian government page](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/visitors/proof-funds-financial-support.html) provides the actual guidance to IRCC staff. It is notably bare of any reference to specific numbers.

> - bank statement(s) or deposit book(s) of applicant (and spouse) that show accumulated savings
> - applicant's (and spouse's) letter of employment or employment book, providing name of employer, applicant's position/occupation, date employment commenced and annual earnings
> - host's or family member in Canada (and spouse's) evidence of income: such as previous year Revenue Canada Notice of Assessment indicating annual income; or alternately, letter from employer(s) showing position, date employment commenced and annual earnings
> - evidence of size of family for host or family member in Canada (to equate earnings with size of family to ensure ability to support long-term visit)

There is no point which either states or implies a particular amount of money that is "good enough".

Among the [eligibility and admission considerations](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/visitors/eligibility-admissibility-considerations.html) is section 6. titles *How will you support yourself in Canada?*

> **Things to consider:**
>
> Does the client have the means to be self-supporting or **is someone else willing and able to provide adequate support?**
>
> **Is the person staying in hotels or with relatives or friends?**
>
> Is it reasonable for the foreign national to be staying with the host for the period indicated?
>
> Will the person be travelling within Canada? If so, for how long?
>   What is the source of funds: traveller's cheques or credit cards?
>
> Are there currency restrictions in the home country?
>
> **Additional information:**
>
> Foreign nationals must have enough funds to maintain themselves in Canada without resorting to illegal employment or social assistance.
>
> **When foreign nationals are planning to stay with friends or relatives ensure that the host is willing and able to provide for the visitor during the stay.**
>
> **The amount of money required will depend on the type and the duration of the trip.**

where all emphasis has been added to pertinent considerations.

This further reinforces the lack of a particular "this much or more" requirement and that the decision is largely based on what is reasonable for the person to need balanced in what they can demonstrate is available to support them.